# Sum of large real numbers is integer instead of real

Tags: android, sqlite, floating-point, sum

I created a table with some values:

```
db.execSQL("create table table_test ("
                + "id integer primary key autoincrement," 
                + "money real not null" + ");");

ContentValues cv;
cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("money", "137.38");
db.insert("table_test", null, cv);

cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("money", "136975.00");
db.insert("table_test", null, cv);
```

Then I'm trying to get sum of money:

```
cursor = db.query("table_test", new String[] { "total(money) as money" }, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
      do {
        String money = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("money"));
        Log.d(tag, "money=" + money);
      } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
cursor.close();
```

The answer is supposed to be 137112.38, but it rounds it to 137112 - I don't understand why.

If I don't enter large numbers it works fine, but with large numbers I only get the integer part of the result.

Comment: these don't look that large to me

Comment: why don't you getDouble rather than getString ?

Comment: Why `getString()` when it's a double? Why `if (cursor.moveToFirst()) { do{}while(cursor.moveToNext())`? `while(cursor.moveToNext(){}` is simpler and enough